# Need a Way to Disable IE9 Browser Caching

Tags: javascript, html, flash, browser, internet-explorer-9

I have a Flash application that sends a getURL request for an image file every 60 seconds.

This works fine in all browsers except IE9 with Internet Option set to automatically check for  newer versions of stored pages.

I setup Charles proxy (http://xk72.com) to watch the requests being sent by my flash app and confirmed that the request is being surpressed by IE9 when the setting is set to Auto, but works fine if I change the setting to check everytime I visit the webpage.  This, however, is not an option!  I need this to work in all browsers regardless of how the options are set.

Even if I do a page refresh (F5), the ASP page does not reload.  The only way to get it to reload is close the browser and restart it.

I have tried adding content headers to disable caching but it does not appear to work.

For Example, here is my request headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date    Sun, 02 Oct 2011 23:58:31 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Expires Tue, 09 Nov 2010 14:59:39 GMT
Cache-control   no-cache
max-age 0
Content-Length  9691
Content-Type    text/html
Set-Cookie  ASPSESSIONIDACQBSACA=ECJPCLHADMFBDLCBHLJFPBPH; path=/
Cache-control   private
```

I have read the Microsoft blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/07/14/caching-improvements-in-internet-explorer-9.aspx) which states that if I add the content headers, the browser should respect my request, but it obviously does not.

I don't think this is a Flash issue since the html page that holds the Flash object will not even reload.

Answer (score 2):

You can append a random number to the end of the url.

Comment: It's like they're trying to make it as hard as possible to make websites.

Comment: Its bad enough that you have to have two sets of code, one for IE and one for everyone else, but now it does not even behave the same way in IE based on which version of it you are using.  This is not the only problem that IE9 has caused my Flash Apps.  I have a client who has been using an App for years that I made for him in Flash and when he upgraded his browser by accident, it all stopped working for him and we had to install Google Chrome to get it operational again!